# What is least dataset for Learning using CNN?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

What is the least smallest sample that can be learned using CNN for a research? I have 60 datasets of large images (20, 20, 20) for three classes.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is a very broad question: it depends on your dataset and what your research question is. You can augment a small dataset to improve results but more data is generally better. I would suggest reading Deep Learning with Python by F Chollet to get to grips with some techniques (especially ch 5 for computer vision examples).

Answer (score 0):

If you're a bit creative then you can really use any amount of pictures (assuming you have at least like 30). If you only have a very small amount of pictures, you just need to use transfer learning instead of training on just your pictures. Essentially you import a pre-trained model (ResNet-50 for example) and then you just continue to train on just your pictures, while freezing the weights in most of the early portions of the network.

By doing this, your network will already know how to detect many key building block features and you'll be able to train your network despite your small dataset.

Here's a link to learn more about transfer learning

https://www.kaggle.com/suniliitb96/tutorial-keras-transfer-learning-with-resnet50